# my calculator created in html,css,js has a problem of not fitting in any screen size

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, fullscreen

so I created a calculator using html,css,js . In pc/big screen size it looks great. But in smaller screen size like phone/tablet it completely cuts off and doesn't adjust to the size. Here is example pictures:

[1080x2280 screen size picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbDV7.png)

[720x1280 screen size picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooNEI.png)

as you can see it cuts off the text and sides of the calculator on the 720x1280

but I want it to not cut off. I did a lot of searching but couldn't get any help. I would be happy if you helped me.

here is the code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Smooth Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="calculator dark">
            <div class="theme-toggler active">
                <i class="toggler-icon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="display-screen">
                <div id="display"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="clear">C</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="/">&divide;</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="*">&times;</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="backspace">&laquo;</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="7">7</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="8">8</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="9">9</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="-">&minus;</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="4">4</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="5">5</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="6">6</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="&plus;">+</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="1">1</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="2">2</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="3">3</button></td>
                        <td rowspan="2"><button class="btn-equal" id="equal">&equals;</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id="(">&lpar;</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-number" id="0">0</button></td>
                        <td><button class="btn-operator" id=")">&rpar;</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>&copy; 2022 | AK PR</p>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Product-Sans';
    src: url('font.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

* {
    font-family: Product-Sans;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom right, rgba(79,51,176,1.0),rgba(210,53,165));
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.calculator {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #000;
}

.theme-toggler {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}

.theme-toggler.active {
    color: #333;
}

.theme-toggler.active::before {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.theme-toggler::before {
    content: '';
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #333;
    z-index: -1;
}

#display {
    margin: 0 10px;
    height: 150px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 270px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }

#display::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
}

button {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}

button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

button#equal {
    height: 130px;
}

/* light theme */

.calculator {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.calculator #display {
    color: #0a1e23;
}

.calculator button#clear {
    background-color: #ffd5d8;
    color: #fc4552;
}

.calculator button.btn-number {
    background-color: #c3eaff;
    color: #000000;
}

.calculator button.btn-operator {
    background-color: #ffd0fb;
    color: #f967f3;
  }
  
  .calculator button.btn-equal {
    background-color: #adf9e7;
    color: #000;
  }

  /* dark theme */

  .calculator.dark {
    background-color: #071115;
  }

  .calculator.dark #display {
    color: #f8fafb;
  }

  .calculator.dark button#clear {
    background-color: #2d191e;
    color: #bd3740;
  }

  .calculator.dark button.btn-number {
    background-color: #1b2f38;
    color: #f8fafb;
  }

  .calculator.dark button.btn-operator {
    background-color: #2e1f39;
    color: #aa00a4;
  }
  
  .calculator.dark button.btn-equal {
    background-color: #223323;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
```

Comment: You may need to set the `meta viewport` for the `height`. And use the CSS `@media screen` to customize the styles respecting to the screen sizes.

Comment: you're using sizes in pixels everywhere - of course your design has a fixed size

Comment: You have fixed height on `#display`, `button`. If you want it to be appears on different screen size, learn more about CSS media query, mobile first design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I went through your code there is no code for making your page responsive .You should use media query to make it responsive for different screens that you use to access your page.Go through about responsive webpages and media query that will help you solve this

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries so that you can design for different screen resolution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).